# How to select a specific row and update one of the cells in JQuery Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, datatables

I have been searching through documents and I can't find a way to get a specific row I need in a datatable. I have a field called siteName that is unique. Is there a function in datatables I can use to search based on that cell?

```
$(".change-button-js").click(
                function (e, f, g, h) {
                    $.post(
                        "/Response/Change",
                        {
                            surveyId: $(e.delegateTarget).attr("value")
                        }
                    ).done(function (data) {
                            let rowId = tbl.fnFindCellRowIndexes(data.site, 0);
                            console.log(rowId)
                            let result = tbl.cell(rowId, 2).data();
                            console.log(result)

                    });
                }
            );
```

In the done function, I have been looking for to see if there is any function I can use to get that specific row in datatables. I am trying to access the index so then I can use .cell function to update that cell.

Comment: _"is not working"_ does not work for us, as a problem description.

Comment: I have updated it. I meant it returns "is not a function".

Comment: Sounds like you failed to notice that this method is provided by a _plugin_ then ...? https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnFindCellRowIndexes

Comment: It came with the project. I am using ASP.NET Core. I am wondering if there is any function in datatables that I can use to select a row based on the field or If I can get the index of the row using an attribute of the element.

Comment: "_any function in datatables that I can use...?_" -  Use [`search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) to find a row based on data in the table. Use [`row().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) to update the relevant row (and to change the specific cell's data you want to change). Combine thees two API functions to do what I think you need to do.

Comment: It would perhaps be easier to be more specific, if you could provide a [mre] with some suitable data, showing your attempt. See also questions such as [update DataTables row data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47912682/12567365) - and probably various similar questions. Those may give you some more ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to get the current `RowId` through the value of `data.site`, and then change the value of a certain cell in this row?

Try this way:

```
let rowId = tbl.row(':contains('+data.site+')').data().id;
console.log(rowId);
let result = tbl.cell(rowId-1, 2).data("Changed Value");
```

It is worth noting that the `rowId` of DataTable starts from `1` by default, but the `index value of the row` is used when using `table.cell()`, which starts from `0` by default. so you need to use `rowId-1`.